# Grep Info then only display text between single quotes?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, ssh

So, I'm working on a basic Wordpress bash script and I need to obtain the Database info from the wp-config.php file.

I have managed to grep the DB information but I'm having issue with regex to get the database name or user only.

```
root@server [/home/user/public_html/]# grep -Ei "DB" wp-config.php | awk '{print $2}' | sed s/\'//g
user_mywp);
user_mywp);
mydbpassword);
```

That's what I've tried but I'm sure that's terrible.

Here is how the original output looks with just a **grep DB wp-config.php**

```
define('DB_NAME', 'user_mywp');
define('DB_USER', 'user_mywp');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mydbpassword');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of grep, just use awk one-liner:

```
awk -F "[,() ']+" '$2 ~ /^DB_/{print $3}' wp-config.php
user_mywp
user_mywp
mydbpassword
```

**UPDATE:** To get values one at a time:

```
> awk -F "[,() ']+" '$2 == "DB_NAME" {print $3}' wp-config.php 
user_mywp
> awk -F "[,() ']+" '$2 == "DB_USER" {print $3}' wp-config.php 
user_mywp
> awk -F "[,() ']+" '$2 == "DB_PASSWORD" {print $3}' wp-config.php 
mydbpassword
```

**Explanation:** This awk uses field separator as `[,() ']+` which one or more of listed characters in `[ and ]` and gets only interested data in in `$2, $3` etc.

Comment: That worked! How would I print the first line only? I'm looking at NR==1 but getting nothing but 0's.

Comment: You can do: `awk -F "[,() ']+" '$2 ~ /^DB_/{print $3; exit}' wp-config.php` to get first record only.

Comment: What if I want to do it for the 2nd or 3rd line? Could you also give me a little explanation please? I know regex is being used to weed out DB_.

Comment: Added some explanation also.